# Getting ObjectBox to work with LiveData and Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, objectbox

I have some working code that uses Room, where I have a function in my repository that looks like this:

```
fun getCharacters(context: Context): LiveData<List<CharacterEntity>> {
    return db.characterDAO().getAll()
}
```

And my ViewModel simply look like this (just returning the LiveData):

```
class CharactersViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

val characters = RickAndMortyRepository.getInstance(application).getCharacters(application)

}
```

Now I would like to convert this to use ObjectBox instead to test it out, but I can not wrap my head around it... I tried altering my repository methos to this:

```
fun getCharacters(context: Context): ObjectBoxLiveData<List<Character>> {
    val characters = ObjectBox.boxStore.boxFor(Character::class.java)
    return ObjectBoxLiveData<List<Character>>(characters.query().build())
    //return db.characterDAO().getAll()
}
```

But there is a type mismatch as the query return "ObjectBoxLiveData and not a list... But I am trying to query for all the Character objects/documents, but how on earth should I build this?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to specify `ObjectBoxLiveData<List<Character>>`. By looking at the source code you can see that `ObjectBoxLiveData` is defined as `ObjectBoxLiveData<T> extends LiveData<List<T>>`. So just do:

```
fun getCharacters(context: Context): ObjectBoxLiveData<Character> {
    val characters = ObjectBox.boxStore.boxFor(Character::class.java)
    return ObjectBoxLiveData<Character>(characters.query().build())
}
```

Full documentation: https://docs.objectbox.io/android/livedata-arch.-comp.

ViewModel example: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-examples/blob/780563ccb46d3198c70669f91910eaaea5ed72c7/android-app-arch/src/main/java/io/objectbox/example/NoteViewModel.java